# How do I select an element that has any of a few different classes?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a table with a bunch of little cells.

```
<table class="epic-table">
    <tr>
        <td class="evil">
        <td class="foo">
        <td class="bar">
        <td class="baz">
        <!-- About 2 dozen more with different classes -->
    </tr>
</table>
```

I need a selector that will grab only the `td`s with with classes `foo`, `bar`, or `baz`. The naive solution would be to make the selector `td.foo, td.bar, td.baz`, but I wonder if there isn't a better selector to do the same thing without having to repeat `td` for each class.

Edit for context: This is going into the `filter` option for a [`selectable`](http://jqueryui.com/selectable/) operation on these particular cells. I am not sure if this option accepts only strings or if it also accepts jQuery objects.

Comment: You can use `filter()` method: `$('td').filter('.foo, .bar, .baz')`  but that's depend what you mean by `better`?!

Comment: I think is not possible using selector, the way I see possible is `$('td').filter('.foo, .bar, .baz')`, but I don't really see it as a improvement

Comment: Since the child elements of the `tr` are always `td`, you don't need to specify that in the `filter` option. Just use `filter: '.foo, .bar, .baz'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not yet a selector — that is being proposed in an [upcoming standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#matches) and jQuery doesn't offer any of its own selectors, but it does provide the `.filter()` method which works just as well:

```
$('td').filter('.foo, .bar, .baz');
```

Comment: I get a "Bikeshed failed" error page from your link to the standard.

Comment: @Barmar: Huh. Looks like an error on their side. With any luck it'll be fixed on their next build. I could link to the WD on www.w3.org instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$('tr').find('.foo,.bar,.baz')
```